# How to type function params and make return type inferrable

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to create a standard type for a function that'll always receive the same type of params, but the ReturnType of the function will depend on the function's inferrable body.

So far I have these two ways to get the job done partially:

I can type the function's params, but the response doesn't get inferred anymore.

```ts
type Handler = (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => unknown
const getExamples: Handler = async (req, res) => {
  // req gets typed as 'NextApiRequest'
  return db.example.findMany()
}
// ReturnType gets typed as unknown
export type GetExamplesResponse = ReturnType<typeof getExamples>
```

[image]

I can also infer the function's ReturnType, but the params are now implicitly any.

```ts
const getExamples = async (req, res) => {
  // req is implicitly "any"
  return db.example.findMany()
}

// ReturnType gets typed as Promise<Example[]>
export type GetExamplesResponse = ReturnType<typeof getExamples>
```

[image]

Is there a way to combine the best of both approaches into a single generic type/interface that'll let my IDE know the types of `req` & `res` and at the same time allow the ReturnType to be inferrable?

[Here's a typescript playground example without the imported types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgOwCYBsICcoF4oAp0QCOAXFAM7DoCWCA5gDRQFmkXV0CU2AfFAK4IA1ggD2AdwQBYAFAyEcALYQyYOAGNoAeQTQA3jKiGoakQgpRaEYAFEAHorBoWsRKgzYocMiARq8BQkZmLixefWkjSKgAemimIgsrMihQSCRPZIByNhpaTIMowwJgPnQEKAAmAsMAX2qYuIAlK1KEABVwaEtgZNSIdK9%20IVEJeohbMBF0YBTOqABxKzsHJ2aVUzJoHGaSso7IAB4%20kQAzRJt7BUdlbhk62Wl5JRV1aDaxEShwyJMzGe7llcnB4vD4-PgiEFlCEwvVIrF4oQoFRklQgVQ1FRgCgQFAAESIEB4uFGYqtSr1e71BE7Vr7LpJWZpDJQAAK6BEChREAOCD4CgARhhbhEjONJtMmdBFhcVso1pMzFsoLS9p0jp1TudAdcyCKakA)

Comment: In short, not possible. You would need to wrap it in another function call, but I guess it is not desirable.

Comment: I'd be okay with using several functions or classes, as long as it's reusable, it's a valid solution

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mqQPZm) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  There should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Why don't you just use `const getExamples = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {`? Then the return type is inferred. But inferred return types can't be _checked_ (and have to be determined through control flow analysis, which can be quite slow), so it's better to be explicit about them, especially given that you apparently want to use that type.

Comment: You could do use rest params like https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAchAewCCYCWAlCBHArhAzsFALxQDeUAZgPbUBcUhATqgHYDmUAvgFCiSwEyNJnxhqrfNFIUARgEMmDVjgC2siE248+4aAAVF81fhJQA2nEQoM2PIQA0g6yILjJEALo6AxhMJQCACMZvL4IKw+UAAUAHTx5kzYTkn4ngyGTMb4AJQkAHxQSVixNNRQAPQVUPpM1KqoUgA8zGzs+Tx+kkQIAEyh4ZEx8bGJyUUE6TVGJnnEhamxClpVNXUNzSrqmvlAA

Comment: Or wrapper func https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAchAewCCYCWAlCBHArhAzsFALxQDeUAZgPbUBcUhATqgHYDmUAvgFCiSwEyNJnxhqrfNFIUARgEMmDVjgC2siE248eAYwmEouphHnAIACXmsAJgBtNJKAB4AKgBoAfAAoAFtftNBm8TLAY4RBQMbDxCdygTfHChKNFxSQgAShJPKFds4lz-WwcmAG4dAHpKqBDsZMiRGIJgeMSG4WixAyycqAAFJmpVVClnZjZ2Tz0DIgQARidjU3MrEs1veXwQVl1a0LaCAtyyHihzhIhgHCZWS6wAOhpqHi5Mqpq6sMFG6NwWw5JH6dNI9Y4DIYjMYqdSaab6SRzeAAJiWJjMlgCpU2212+2wgPBpwul2ut0u+AeCiYr0yQA

Comment: Are you looking to annotate return type `async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse): Promise<Example[]> => { ... }`

Comment: Added typescript playground example, the idea behind this is to give developers on the project a reusable interface to generate endpoints and consume their ReturnType on a NextJS frontend with redux RTKQuery. 
Loved the wrapper example btw.

Comment: @AlekseyL. both your comments can be considered answers to the original question, if you post it as an answer I'll gladly mark it as the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify the function type explicitly `const getExamples: Handler` - it will override the inferred type. Instead you could provide the type for
the rest parameter:

```
type Params = [NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse]

const ex1 = async (...[req, res]: Params) => req.foo // Promise<string>
const ex2 = async (...[req, res]: Params) => res.bar // Promise<number>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAchAewCCYCWAlCBHArhAzsFALxQDeUAZgPbUBcUhATqgHYDmUAvgFCiSwEyNJnxhqrfNFIUARgEMmDVjgC2siE248%204aAAVF81fhJQA2nEQoM2PIQA0g6yILjJEALo6AxhMJQCACMZvL4IKw%20UAAUAHTx5kzYTkn4ngyGTMb4AJQkAHxQSVixNNRQAPQVUPpM1KqoUgA8zGzs%20Tx%20kkQIAEyh4ZEx8bGJyUUE6TVGJnnEhamxClpVNXUNzSrqmvlAA)

Other option would be using "factory" function:

```
const createHandler = <T>(handler: (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => T) => handler;

// (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => Promise<string>
const ex1 = createHandler(async (req, res) => {
    return req.foo
})

// (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => Promise<number>
const ex2 = createHandler(async (req, res) => {
    return res.bar
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAchAewCCYCWAlCBHArhAzsFALxQDeUAZgPbUBcUhATqgHYDmUAvgFCiSwEyNJnxhqrfNFIUARgEMmDVjgC2siE248eAYwmEouphHnAIACXmsAJgBtNJKAB4AKgBoAfAAoAFtftNBm8TLAY4RBQMbDxCdygTfHChKNFxSQgAShJPKFds4lz-WwcmAG4dAHpKqBDsZMiRGIJgeMSG4WixAyycqAAFJmpVVClnZjZ2Tz0DIgQARidjU3MrEs1veXwQVl1a0LaCAtyyHihzhIhgHCZWS6wAOhpqHi5Mqpq6sMFG6NwWw5JH6dNI9Y4DIYjMYqdSaab6SRzeAAJiWJjMlgCpU2212%202wgPBpwul2ut0u%20AeCiYr0yQA)